# SQL - Select only statement: How do create something similar to a "Vlookup"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am new to stackoverflow so hope I am phrasing this clear enough.

I have a lot of data on our sql server and can only use a Select statement to extract data. I am looking now to extract a certain part out of a part name so I can see how many of that type we use:

```
SELECT      CASE 
            WHEN Part.Part_No like '%B-123%' THEN 'B-123' 
            WHEN Part.Part_No like '%B-456%' THEN 'B-456' 
            WHEN Part.Part_No like '%IW-10%' THEN 'IW-10'
            WHEN Part.Part_No like '%T-TLT%' THEN 'T-TLT' 
            WHEN Part.Part_No like '%B-TLT3060%' THEN 'B-TLT3060' 
            ELSE NULL END AS Type
FROM   dbo.CATEGORY
```

So rather then writing hundreds of these lines, I was wondering if I can add these in a table and then run through the table like a VLookup. But I can only do it in the select statement without creating new tables ( I am not too sure how this would work with a temp table).

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post the DB schema of yours with sample data as well? A minimal verifiable working example is what is required here...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: And for some help with how to post schema & sample data: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I am using SQL  Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for managing your lookup table. You can then join (left join) your table and the lookup table, using LIKE as a join clause.

This query should do it:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT '%B-123%' AS a, 'B-123' AS b
              UNION SELECT '%B-456%', 'B-456' 
              UNION SELECT '%IW-10%', 'IW-10'
              UNION SELECT '%T-TLT%', 'T-TLT' 
              UNION SELECT '%B-TLT3060%', 'B-TLT3060')
SELECT c.b
  FROM dbo.CATEGORY t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cte c
    ON Part.Part_No LIKE c.a
```

Depending on your data and table structure, it could happen that it gets more than one result for each row (in case one part_no matches more than one case). If that's your case, you could limit it using a GROUP BY on the primary key of the table.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that looks tidy, I'll give that a try.